# WIX Installer Trim Edit Control to Ensure No White Space?

Tags: validation, installation, wix, controls

I have a custom WIX dialog that has an edit control on it (text box).  I want to ensure that the user has typed something into it before proceeding to the next screen.

The code below works great if the edit control remains empty:

```
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BHSInstallDirDlg"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted<>""]]></Publish>
```

However the problem I have is if they enter white space (spacebar) in the field this check will fail.  Is there anyway I can trim white spaces?  Or is there a different approach I might look at to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is a custom action which trims the property value and saves it. You can run it through a [DoAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368322%28VS.85%29.aspx) control event before the NewDialog event.

Since you need to save an installer property, the custom action must be able to receive the installation handle. So it can be a DLL or VBScript.

You can find a C++ DLL custom action tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Comment: This worked great.  I created a custom action in C#, trimed the Property, and set it back to the session.